# Named Pipes C# Server C++ .dll Client Not Working?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, ipc, named-pipes

So I'm trying to use Named Pipes to communicate between a C# server and C++ .dll client that I will inject.
My named pipes works fine when used with a C++ Console App but when I use the same method in the .dll the Server and Client connect fine but when I try use NamedPipeServerStream.Write() my C# app freezes. They are both x64 if that matters at all.

Any ideas as to why?

C# Server

```
    Thread ServerThread;
    private static NamedPipeServerStream _server;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServerThread = new Thread(ServerThreadSub);

        ServerThread.Start();
    }

    void ServerThreadSub()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _server = new NamedPipeServerStream("ConsolePipe", PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message);
            _server.WaitForConnection();
            do
            {
            } while (_server.IsConnected);
            _server.Close();
        }
    }

    private void text_CurrentCommand_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            if (text_CurrentCommand.Text != "")
            {
                if (_server.IsConnected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] buff = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text_CurrentCommand.Text);
                        _server.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length); //Freezes here
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Log("Client Disconnected, Command Not Processed.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log("Command Not Processed. Client Not Connected.");
                }
            }
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

C++ Client

```
#define PIPE_NAME L"\\\\.\\pipe\\ConsolePipe"
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024

HANDLE hPipe;

DWORD WINAPI Main(LPVOID threadArgs)
{
    while (true)
    {
        do
        {
            Sleep(1000);
            hPipe = CreateFile(PIPE_NAME, GENERIC_READ, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, nullptr);
            if (hPipe == NULL || hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) DeleteFile(PIPE_NAME);
        } while (hPipe == NULL || hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

        DWORD mode = PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE;

        SetNamedPipeHandleState(hPipe, &mode, nullptr, nullptr);

        bool success = false;
        DWORD read;

        while (true)
        {
            char chBuff[BUFF_SIZE];
            success = ReadFile(hPipe, chBuff, (DWORD)strlen(chBuff), &read, nullptr);
            if (success)
            {
            }
            if (!success) break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also another query I have that isn't really important, is there any way to get NamedPipeServerStream.IsConnected to refresh without performing a Read() or Write()?

Thanks in advance c:

Comment: Using strlen(chBuff) in the ReadFile() call is not correct, that generates an entirely random number.  Use BUFF_SIZE instead.

Comment: Ok I'll try that c:

Comment: That worked, thank you so much! c:

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a dll then i suggest you to use **`DllMain()`** as entry-point which might be one of the main reason your program is not working

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,  // handle to DLL module
    DWORD fdwReason,     // reason for calling function
    LPVOID lpReserved )  // reserved
{
    // Perform actions based on the reason for calling.
    switch( fdwReason ) 
    { 
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
         // Initialize once for each new process.
         // Return FALSE to fail DLL load.
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
         // Do thread-specific initialization.
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
         // Do thread-specific cleanup.
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
         // Perform any necessary cleanup.
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;  // Successful DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.
}
```

more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't put that in the post because wasn't really relevant to the problem, everything else is working fine, just the Write() crashes it :c